# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm sometimes getting an error in my chrome console saying *'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'*  I'm not sure what is causing it but I believe it is to do with a JavaScript setInterval method I'm using in my .js file.

I'm using the setInterval method to hide a sticky top nav after 4 seconds of inactivity by the user, the sticky nav reappears after the user moves their mouse or makes a keypress.

Also, while the below code is working as described in Chrome, in Firefox it only works once, i.e. the sticky nav is hidden once & reapears on mouse/keypress but does not disappear again.

What may be causing this error?

Why is Firefox behaving differently to Chrome?

I think may be making an error in how I'm using the setInterval method.  In the code below, I set the interval at the beginning & clear the interval once the user clicks on the nav button (i.e. `.mk-nav-responsive-link`), I then re-start the interval method when the user clicks on the nav button to close the menu.

```
<!-- CODE ABOVE OMITTED FOR BREVITY -->

    // Hide Nav on User Inactivity START
    var userInactivity = 1;
    var userInactivityInterval = setInterval(function(){userInactivityTimer()},1000);
    function userInactivityTimer(){
        if(userInactivity == 4 && jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (vh/8)){
            jQuery('.mk-nav-responsive-link img').fadeOut();
            userInactivity = 1;
        }
        userInactivity = userInactivity+1;
//        console.log(userInactivity);
//        console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop());

        jQuery(document).bind('mousemove keypress', function() {
            jQuery('.mk-nav-responsive-link img').fadeIn();
            userInactivity = 1;
        });
    }
    // Hide Nav on User Inactivity END

    // CUSTOM DROP DOWN MENU TRANSITIONS START
    jQuery('.mk-nav-responsive-link').toggle(function() {
      // RESPONSIVE FIX TO SHOW THE ENTIRE DROP DOWN MENU ON SMALL HEIGHT SCREENS
      if (jQuery(window).height() < 405) {
            jQuery("#mk-responsive-nav").css('height','581px');
            jQuery("#responsive-nav-bg").animate({
            top:'0',
            height:'575px'
          },175, 'linear');
        } else {
            jQuery("#responsive-nav-bg").animate({
            top:'0',
            height:'100vh'
          },175, 'linear');
        }
      jQuery(".mk-desktop-logo").attr('src',"/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/images/EW-logo-white.png");
      jQuery(".mk-nav-responsive-link > img").attr('src',"/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/images/x-close-menu.png");
      jQuery(".mk-nav-responsive-link > img").css('padding-top','0');
      jQuery(".mk-nav-responsive-link > img").css('padding-right','0');
      jQuery('.mk-go-top.on').css({'display' : 'none'});
      jQuery('.mk-desktop-logo').css({'position' : 'fixed'});
      clearInterval(userInactivityInterval);

    }, function() {
        jQuery("#responsive-nav-bg").animate({
        top:'87px',
        height:'0'
      },250, 'linear');
      if (jQuery(window).width() < 405) {
            jQuery(".mk-desktop-logo").attr('src',"/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/images/EW-logo-responsive.png");
        } else {
            jQuery(".mk-desktop-logo").attr('src',"/wp-content/uploads/EW-logo.png");
        }
      jQuery(".mk-nav-responsive-link > img").attr('src',"/wp-content/themes/jupiter-child/images/burger-menu-icon.png");
      jQuery(".mk-nav-responsive-link > img").css('padding-top','10px');
      jQuery(".mk-nav-responsive-link > img").css('padding-right','5px');
      jQuery('.mk-go-top.on').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
      jQuery('.mk-desktop-logo').css({'position' : 'relative'});
      userInactivityInterval = setInterval(function(){userInactivityTimer()},1000);
    });
    // CUSTOM DROP DOWN MENU TRANSITIONS END

<!-- CODE BELOW OMITTED FOR BREVITY -->
```

Comment: Move your mousemove event out of the interval fn. This may not be the problem, but you're rebinding it every second. That's not good mojo. You only bind it once. #YOBO

Comment: I have a hunch that two intervals are being run simultaneously somehow. Add two different console logs to the two spots you set the interval and test if that's the case.

Comment: @SamP Thank you, moving the mousemove event outside of the function seems to have fixed it :)  The console error is no longer appearing.

Comment: can you post you html? I'm trying to reproduce this but i'm really missing the elements. http://jsbin.com/yiqemu/1/edit

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to move your mousemove event out of the `interval` function. You're killing your CPU by rebinding the event every second. This event only needs to be bound *once*.

Remember that it's expensive to bind events on a large scale. Try to minimize your bindings at all times.

You only bind it once. #YOBO

Comment: I'm definitely using #YOBO in my comments